# protractor latest version not working with eclipse neon

Tags: eclipse, protractor

I am not able to run protractor latest version in eclipse neon 
I was using 5.10.0 and I had to downgrade to 4.0.2 to get it worked .

Is there any properties to be set so that I can run the protractor latest version in eclipse

Comment: To answer this better ... can you add more details on how configured eclipse to run protractor tests? .. did you do it via angularJs plugin? or a custom run configuration?

Comment: I did it using Angular JS plugin